# Jackrabbit lucene ItemNotFoundException - how to reproduce/what causes corrupt index

Tags: lucene, jackrabbit, corrupt

It appears our lucene index is becoming corrupt as we see these exceptions suddenly occurring. We fix it by deleting the index folders so that the index gets rebuilt.

Problem is, we haven't been able to reliably reproduce this exception making it hard to find out whats causing it.

Anyone know what jackrabbit actions are most likely to corrupt the search index?

Answer (score 0):

We have this kind of problems with hard 'reboot' of Jackrabbit like killing the server running the application. Maybe some of it will disappear with the use of Lucene 3.6 (in Jackrabbit 2.5.1).

Comment: Do you know what operations were being performed at the time? Are you able to consistently reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it may be down to the container interrupting and hitting a [jackrabbit bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-3469).